# How to calculate hours between two timestamps while some time ranges should not be taken into account

Tags: excel

I need some clever way of solving my following problem in Excel. I have some data on downtime of certain devices and need to calculate the time it took a certain party to solve the issue of the device.

I have start datetimes and end datetimes of the device downtime like so:

```
Device     Start               End
1          12-8-2019 9:41:14       12-8-2019 16:03:24
2          12-8-2019 9:43:33       13-8-2019 8:44:22
3          12-8-2019 12:09:50      19-8-2019 8:40:00
```

The problem is these devices are not accesible all day and so the service party should not be accounted for downtime during periods the devices are not accesible for repair. The acces hours are stored as follows:

```
Device    Monday from    Monday to   Tuesday from   Tuesday to ....
1         08:00          20:00       10:00          23:59
2         00:00          20:00       08:00          20:00
```

My problem is how to calculate the number of hours between the start and end of downtime, but not counting the overlap with non access hours between the start and end of downtime in Excel?

Comment: Take a look at [this website](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-work-hours-between-dates-and-times) for guidance in building your formula.

Comment: I guess there is no way to use variable working times? My access hours are not the same every day of the week

Comment: I believe you'll need to consider a VBA solution to use variable working times. That should be rather straightforward code.